# How do I make an external URL open on a new tab?

Tags: 7

When I try putting a link like `<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">` on the link path, I get the following error message:

> The path '//www.example.com/" target="_blank">' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

Is there a way to have the external URL opened in a new tab?

Comment: If you are developing a module you could use [url_is_external](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url_is_external/7) to see if a URL is external. Then you could add a target based on the return value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can target your menu tag with jquery using its ID you can put something like this in an JS file that you'll add in your theme via your_theme.info

```
Drupal.behaviors.externalMenu = function(context, settings) {
    $('#menu_id').attr('target', '_blank');
};
```

Or you can use the [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

Comment: I'm using superfish menu on zen theme and my menus doesn't have own ID  thanks,

Comment: Yes that's a problem in some situations, hopefully you can use a module like [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to add some custom attributes and it supports the "target" attributes so I think you get your answer, I'll edit mine.

Comment: I didn't know about the Menu attributes module, thanks.

Comment: Thanks `menu attribute` works perfect Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Not per menu item. However, the [External links](http://drupal.org/project/extlink) project allows to open all external links in a new window and indicates them as such with an icon.

Comment: thank you! i tried that module, i don't want to open all external link by new window. i have one menu and i want to open that menu link on a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are entering `<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">`, when Drupal is expecting only the link (`http://www.example.com`, in your case).

If you would enter `http://www.example.com`, Drupal would notice it's an external link, and it will allow you to use it.
I tried adding a link to drupal.org, and as you can see, Drupal accepted it (it's the link shown as "Drupal").

[image: screenshot]

For how to open the link in a new browser tab, the other answers already explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project called "[Menu Target](https://drupal.org/project/menu_target)" that allows you to do just that. Maybe that helps those who only need individual menu links to open in a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make all external links open in a new window you can rewrite theme_links in your current theme, if not use menu_attributes module as given above.

```
function yourtheme_name_link($variables) {
  // Add target blank to all external links.
  if (url_is_external($variables['path'])) {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  }
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this answer from the board which was a big help, this may work for you as well:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-node-166 a').attr('target', '_blank');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

in my case, i referenced the page class, then the 'a' and that made the links on that page open in new window.  I am going to do a bit more selector chaining to I can better pinpoint the specific menu in the sidebar.